# Prevent tabbing of elements behind an overlay

Tags: html, tabindex

I am working on tabbing through the whole web page using the keyboard(tab key, shift+tab key) and everything is working fine and smooth. Also when i keep pressing the tab key, the focus cycles through all the elements(address bar, elements, back to address bar and so on).

Now in some cases, i have an modal and an transparent overlay on top of my content. Now when this happens, when i use tab key, i move from the left menu to the overlay and from the last focusible element on the overlay, i have to force the focus to the body element(or the address bar). So Basically when there is an overlay, i want to ignore the element below the overlay from tabbing. Is there any way i can achieve it cleanly?

I was thinking of setting tabindex=-1 for all elements under the overlay but any other better approach would be the most welcome

Thanks

Comment: I like accessibility questions! There should be more of them on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

This is an oldish question, but I just ran into this issue today, so I thought I'd share my solution.

As long as you know the tab order of items in your overlay, you can just add a blur event listener on the final item and use it to move the focus back to the first item in your overlay:

`lastElementInOverlay.addEventListener('blur', function() 
  { firstElementInOverlay.focus(); });`

It strikes me that this would be easier than changing the tabIndex of all the elements under the overlay (and then having to change them back when the overlay is gone.

Answer (score 3):

The 'modern/future' solution to this problem seems to be the `inert` attribute...

So taking the example above, it would look like this with overlay opened

```
<div id="menu" inert>
    <a>
    <a>
    <a>
</div>
[...other code with tabindex]
<div id="overlay">
    <a>
    <a>
    <a>
</div>
```

Now since inert is still a work in progress; you'll need to use the following polyfill (for now): https://github.com/WICG/inert

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking of setting tabindex=-1 for all elements under the overlay but any other better approach would be the most welcome

This is what i usually do when fixing the tabbing of elements.

There is one other solution i can think of:
Setting the overlay tab-element lower then that of the rest. 
Eg:

```
<div menu>
    <a tabindex="10">
    <a tabindex="11">
    <a tabindex="12">
</div>
[...other code with tabindex > 10]
<div overlay>
    <a tabindex="1">
    <a tabindex="2">
    <a tabindex="3">
</div>
```

The downside of this will be that after you have tabbed trough the overlay you will go to the menu again.

Comment: This will not work for me because after the overlay, i want the focus to go to the <body> element, then to the address bar, then again <body> and then to the first focusible element(left menu icon).

Comment: @aneeshere surly you can sett the tabbable order to fit that need and creating a gap in the order where there can or can not be a overlay.
Why would you ever focus an entire <body> element? and on top of that twice?

Comment: I did not mean to say that i will focus on the body. Its actually something the browser does. And it changes from browser to browser. Anyway i fixed this by setting the tabindex to -1 for the underlying focusable elements and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an id like "lastFocusableOverlayElement" to the last focusable HTML-element of your overlay and assign the focus to your trigger element (for example "menu-button") when leaving the last element's focus:

```
$('#lastFocusableOverlayElement').on('blur', function(){
    if ($("body").hasClass("overlay-is-open")){
        $('#toggleOverlay').focus();
    }
});
```

In my case the last focusable element is always visible, regardless of whether the overlay is open. For this reason i needed an if query.  It can be omitted if not necessary.