# JavaScript prevent focus outside an element

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

To improve accessibility, I want to set the modal div with `aria-hidden="false"` only one which is focusable recursively, and prevent any focus outside the modal div.

I can do that with targeting the focus of elements (and prevent clicks by CSS), in the way when the focus moved outside of the modal, immediately refocus it back to the last focused element inside the modal.

I'm not sure if this is the best way, so I would like to receive other ideas.

For note,
I do not like the way with setting `tabindex="-1"` to many elements,
and I also tried to use `element.blur()` which did nothing.

Comment: Some answers here might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514812/prevent-tabbing-of-elements-behind-an-overlay. Inert seems like it may get you your desired result https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert

Comment: @pilchard possible yes, the last 4 answers there.

Comment: @p7dxb is also gave possible good solution with Inert.

Comment: Also take a look at the [modal dialog pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialog-modal/). The [modal dialog example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialog-modal/examples/dialog/) has [working javascript](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialog-modal/examples/dialog/#javascriptandcsssourcecode) that you can use

Comment: [Caniuse inert](https://caniuse.com/?search=inert)

Comment: Actually Inert is not the best solution yet, becasuse need to add and remove inert tag to many other elements, and in case if the modal is inside in another elements(Incorrectly written by previous developers), so need also work hierarchically which is more complex..